# Enable downvoting after a comment

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encouraging people to explain down-votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes)

I asked a question and it got 4 downvotes without any reason? Isn't that downvoting should follow a comment? Or simply because you can downvote for free,you will do it?

Please check my question here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601626/web-sites-to-follow-for-ruby-on-rails-developers

I'm asking this because its not the first time.

Answer (score 5):

> Isn't that downvoting should follow a comment?

No, people are encouraged to explain their downvotes, but are *not* required to do so.

> Or simply because you can downvote for free, you will do it?

If the question doesn't show sufficient prior research and/or at least some minimal effort to solve your problem on your own, of course I'll downvote it.

---

Now, specifically about your question:

- It's *not* a real question, it's a request for a list of resources. The ["don't ask" section](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) in the FAQ explains in some detail why we don't welcome such questions.
- No prior research or any other kind of effort is evident, the downvotes are justified.

Comment: Where can I ask this question? The one i have give the link.

Comment: @SachinPrasad I'm afraid the question isn't appropriate for Stack Exchange in general, there is no site in the network that would accept it.

Comment: Don't be afraid be bold :D

Comment: @SachinPrasad Stack Exchange **is** bold, in that we are doing something so completely different from all the 'forums' out there: We accept only certain kinds of questions which have been shown to be productive for this kind of site, and specifically don't accept certain other ones which have been shown to be unproductive.

Answer (score 2):

Comments should not be compulsory for downvotes. It will reduce the downvoting. The question you have linked is obviously off-topic on Stack Overflow. See our [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) before posting a question. It's not a programming question.